# How does whatsapp implement the feature of text search in the chat?

Tags: java, android, xmpp

I just want to add a search feature in a chat app based on xmpp protocol that could help user to search any message in a chat with a person. I want to do the same in Java while i have the chats stored in local storage of mobile.

Comment: Questions like *How do they do it ?* are clearly off topic and too broad. You better do some research and effort first . Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I did research but not able to find it that's why I am asking over here. I just need some reference. So instead of providing me link for "how to ask a good question", providing "how to do it" would be a better option